# How can I assign a negative number to the function that accepts the UINT parameter

Tags: go, pkcs#11

From the meigk/pkcs11 package.
Is there any way to assign a negative value in the Login function as **userType**?
Because the HSM model that I'm working with, supports one more additional role except for the following standard roles and I want to login with that role.

Standard roles:

```
CKU_SO               uint = 0
CKU_USER             uint = 1
CKU_CONTEXT_SPECIFIC uint = 2
```

Login function source code from https://github.com/miekg/pkcs11/

```
func (c *Ctx) Login(sh SessionHandle, userType uint, pin string) error {
    p := C.CString(pin)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(p))
    e := C.Login(c.ctx, C.CK_SESSION_HANDLE(sh), C.CK_USER_TYPE(userType), p, C.CK_ULONG(len(pin)))
    return toError(e)
}
```

In the C#. I have using the PKCS11Interop package and its login function also accepts only for the uint parameter as userType. But it can be done by using the **unchecked** keyword. So I can put the negative value in the Login function without an error.

Here is my sample code in C# using https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop

```
public enum SpecialRole
{
   CU = -12345
}
session.Login(unchecked((CKU)SpecialRole.CU), Settings.CryptoUserPin);
```

Then, how can I do this in Go? Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If type of the parameter is `uint`, you can only pass values that are [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to the type `uint` (as stated in [Spec: Calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)). And the valid range of `uint` does not include negative numbers.

What you may do is convert your negative value to `uint`. Converting a negative `int` to `uint` is roughly equivalent to subtracting the absolute value from the max value of `int` plus 1. So if your other constants are small, this won't cause a collision.

For example:

```
func main() {
    f(1)
    
    f(math.MaxUint64+1 -10)

    x := -10
    f(uint(x))
}

func f(i uint) {
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UorgU7dIvyi)):

```
1
18446744073709551606
18446744073709551606
```